MAMP PRO Error Message: MySQL is not running, therefore neither databases nor table can be shown
I am using MAMP Pro. When I start the web server, I get the following error message:
"MySQL is not running, therefore neither databases nor table can be shown"

I don’t understand why this is happening, as the MySQL is running (You can see the little tick next to MySQL).
Has anyone got any ideas? I tried contacting Mamp Support. But they are not very helpful and they are very slow to respond. They said "There might be something on your machine which conflicts with MySQL port". However, I don’t see how, as I only recently did a clean install of MacOS. And since then Mamp Pro is the only web related software I have installed.
I would really appreciate some help, Thanks!
Environment: MacOS 12.7.5
MAMP PRO: Version 6.9 (Build 34161 - Universal)
